# Meaning of "to achieve the setup of a disaster recovery plan" (business language)

Tags: phrase-meaning, business-language

From a document I'm translating:

> Business Continuity
> A. Managers shall ensure that procedures within their area of responsibility are carried out correctly to **achieve the setup of** a disaster recovery plan.
> B. There shall be a documented and appropriate method to determine the impact of a disruption of the production and services of the organization following a disaster.
> C. The organization shall document and implement procedures to respond to a disaster in order to recover or maintain its activities to a predetermined level.

What is the meaning of **to achieve the setup of**? Does it mean "in case of a disaster, managers should act properly **to create the initial conditions** necessary for the implementation of a (previously detailed) disaster recovery plan)"?

Answer (score 1):

The AHD (https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=achieve) offers as its second definition of **achieve**:

> To succeed in accomplishing; bring about: achieve a task; achieve an improvement in foreign relations. See Synonyms at perform.

In your quotation, what is being achieved is only the setting up of a plan for disaster recovery. This seems to be confirmed by the requirements to assess the damage when a disaster occurs and document the procedures to respond to a disaster.

That would be my reading, although there’s a chance your option could be what was intended.

Comment: I agree with your reading that the text is talking about establishing the plan in preparation for potential future disasters, not about following the plan after a disaster occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You have the unenviable task of translating pretentious and bloated business prose.

*Managers shall ensure that procedures within their area of responsibility are carried out correctly to achieve the setup of a disaster recovery plan*

Ensuring proper procedure within an area of responsibility is part of the function of a manager so hardly needs to be said.

To achieve the setup is no different from setting up.

Hence the sentence says little more than:

*Managers must set up a disaster recovery plan*

The following sentences - which you do not ask about - show the same self-important and ploddingly procedural approach that stultifies the adaptability and flexibility that would actually be needed if disaster struck.